# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/.../DataConfiguration.class]:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I had a project that was working. I added nearly 2 hundred entities, now I'm getting "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'". I didn't intentionally change anything else.

I'm using Java-style confinguration.

I'm getting the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/cru/cloud/management/config/DataConfiguration.class]: 
            Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:752)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: component property not found: id
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getProperty(Component.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2651)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:2473)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2198)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3788)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    ... 33 more
```

My pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-samples-hellomvc-jc</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>spring-security-samples-hellomvc-jc</name>
  <description>spring-security-samples-hellomvc-jc</description>
  <url>http://spring.io/spring-security</url>
  <properties>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    <!-- spring.version>3.2.11.RELEASE</spring.version -->
    <!-- spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version -->
    <!-- hibernate.entity.manager.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.entity.manager.version -->
    <!-- hibernate.jpa.api.version>1.0.0.Final</hibernate.jpa.api.version -->
    <!-- spring.data.jpa.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version -->
    <!-- slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version -->
    <spring.version>4.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <hibernate.entity.manager.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.entity.manager.version>
    <hibernate.jpa.api.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate.jpa.api.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.7.0.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
  </properties>
  <organization>
    <name>spring.io</name>
    <url>http://spring.io/</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>rwinch</id>
      <name>Rob Winch</name>
      <email>rwinch@gopivotal.com</email>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security</url>
  </scm>
```

My DataConfiguration contains:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {       
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
            vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
            factory.setPackagesToScan("org.cru.cloud.management.core.repository", "org.cru.repository");
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

            return factory;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had an `@Embedded` entity that needed an `@OneToOne` annotation on its reference.